# How to make a Concept Graph in R

Tags: r, text-mining, undirected-graph

R How can I make a concept graph from data. Suppose I have a dataframe of 100 samples.  Each sample contains a paragraph. I want to generate a undirected graph of top concept from the entire data frame. I have gone through numerous article but couldn't find out a soluton. Please Help

Comment: could you explain what you mean with concept graph or upload a picture which illustrates your idea? And what did you try so far?

Comment: concept graph in the sense, Generation of top keywords from the text data, those top keywords will be on nodes.

Comment: Maybe the `igraph` or `comato` or packages might help?